# Django Model field default from Model

Tags: python, django

Consider two models in my `models.py`:

#### Roles:

```py
class Role(models.Model):
    role = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    nickname = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    is_hero = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.role
```

and

#### Players:

```py
class Player(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    role = models.ForeignKey(Role, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    nickname = models.CharField(max_length=255, default="Use the default nickname from the role you just chose but also be able to change it from within this model.")
    is_hero = models.BooleanField(default="Use the default is_hero from the role you just chose but also be able to change it from within this model.")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Also consider that I already made a role called `"Dumbo"` with the nickname `"Dunm"` and is_hero being `False`.

I now go ahead and try to use the role in my new player after setting my player name, I choose my role but how do I use the values of my now chosen role in my new player as the default for nickname and is_hero and at the same time, allow them to be overridden if feel so?

Thanks,

#### Edit:

I've overridden all the Django templates. So I'm not making new forms and rendering them in my custom views. I'm really bad with the terminologies, pardon me. I hope this makes sense.

```
{% load fieldcss %}
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
            {% if fieldset.name %}<h4 class="card-title">{{ fieldset.name }}</h2>{% endif %}
            {% if fieldset.description %}
                <div class="description">{{ fieldset.description|safe }}</div>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            {% for line in fieldset %}
            <div class="row">
                    {% for field in line %}
                            {% if not line.fields|length_is:'1' and not field.is_readonly %}{{ field.errors }}{% endif %}
                            {% if name == "CheckboxInput" %}
                                {{ field.field }}{{ field.label_tag }}

                            {% else %}
                                {{ field|addlabel:field.field.label|safe }}
                                {% if field.is_readonly %}
                                    <div class="readonly">{{ field.contents }}</div>
                                {% else %}
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    {% if line.fields|length_is:'1' %}{{ line.errors }}{% endif %}
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        {{ field|addclass:field.field.auto_id|safe }}
                                        {% if field.field.help_text %}
                                            <span class="form-text">{{ field.field.help_text|safe }}</span>
                                        {% endif %}
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                {% endif %}
                            {% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}
            </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not something you can do in the model, but by passing the values to the form from the view at creation time. For example:

```
class PlayerCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Player
        fields = ('name', 'nickname', 'is_hero')

def create_player_from_role(request, role_id):
    role = get_object_or_404(Role, role_id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PlayerCreateForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            player = form.save(commit=False)
            player.role = role
            player.save()
            return redirect('/')
    else:
        form = PlayerCreateForm(initial={'nickname': role.nickname, 'is_hero': role.is_hero})
    return render(request, 'create_player.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: Oh? Thank you for your reply. I've actually overridden the original Django templates so I'm not using any forms or views. I'm using template tags and filters. Is there a way I can make it work with my current situation. I don't know if forms are used in the default Django templates or not.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean *at all*. How are you using template tags and filters to create a form? Show your template (as an edit to the question).

Comment: Like I'm guessing in order to use this form, I'll have to create a view for it which, I don't want to do. Is there way to make Django use a specific form for a specific class?

Comment: Updated my question.
Or is there a way to use this form as the default change form for my model?

Comment: You haven't really explained anything. You're not creating a form with tags and filters here. But are you trying to do this in the admin? If so I don't know why you didn't say so.

Comment: Yes. I'm really sorry. I just.... I don't know why. I just didn't know the right words. But could you tell me how to do it?

Comment: How do we do it in the admin?

Comment: But now it's not clear how you are intending this to work in the admin. Where are you selecting the role and how do you pass it to the person form?

Comment: Ok. I'm a lot sober now, sorry for the inconvenience.
Basically, All I've done so far is, I've made two models in my `models.py`. What I want to achieve is when I login to the Django admin with my superuser account, I click the Add button for my model and create a new player where I would choose the name, select a role (My role object has a `nickname` and a `is_hero` field). Under the role I just select in my Player model, I also have a `nickname` and a `is_hero` field. I want these fields to be pre-populated or have the default value of the same fields inside the role I just selected.

Comment: I really, sincerely hope that this was clear enough for you to help me, if it isn't please let me know what I should correct.

Comment: Well this is something you could only do with some custom JavaScript and Ajax, unfortunately.

Comment: Oh it's alright. Are there any links you can give me that I can refer to?

Comment: Oh it's alright. Are there any links you can give me that I can refer to?

Comment: Oh my god. No wonder you didn't bother reply. I was so stupid, I should've done more research and paid more attention. I'm really sorry for wasting your time. This actually was the way to go. I'm going to select your answer. Thank you so very much for your time. I will not delete my comments because I want others like me (if there are any) to not go through what I went (The Stupidity of me).